# Procesamiento de CSV de gran tamaño a un array

Tags: php, array, csv

Necesito procesar dos archivos CSV, esto lo hago sin problemas con una función de CSV a array para el primer archivo que pesa 1MB, pero el segundo peso mas de 80 MB y al realizar el procesamiento se consume toda la memoria del servidor, la idea del procesamiento es después de que tenga los array  poder cruzar estos array, realizar unos filtros y exportar a otro CSV.

Se tiene alguna función o método para poder realizar el procesamiento si consumir toda la memoria?, existe alguna otra forma de hacer este procesamiento en PHP?
La función que uso para pasar del CSV al array es:

```
function CSV2Array($archivo, $delimitador = ";")
{
    if (!empty($archivo) && !empty($delimitador) && is_file($archivo)) {
        $array_total = array();
        $array_keys=array();
        $keys_bandera=0;
        $count=0;
        $fp = fopen($archivo, "r");
        while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 10000, ";")) {
            $num = count($data);
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    if($keys_bandera==0){
                        $array_keys [$key] = str_replace("Ó","O",utf8_encode(str_replace(" ","",$value)));
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        $array_total[$count][$array_keys[$key]] = utf8_encode($value);   
                       
                    }
                }
                $count++;
                $keys_bandera=1;
                
            }
       
        fclose($fp);
        return $array_total;
        
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para un CSV tan grande yo no lo convertiría a array para luego procesarlo, sino que lo iría procesando mientras lo leo línea a línea, esta operación mediante un puntero (con fopen y fgetcsv como haces en tu función) da muy buen rendimiento, porque no cargas todo en memoria. El CSV pequeño sí lo puedes cargar inicialmente en un array para luego ir mezclándolo con el grande. Y lo idóneo es tener abierto puntero al archivo CSV nuevo e ir escribiendo línea a línea conforme se van procesando leyendo del grande.

Comment: He hecho esto muchas veces, tengo unas clases que te pueden servir: https://github.com/josecarlosphp/reader y https://github.com/josecarlosphp/writer

Comment: ¿Has probado a aumentar la memoria del servidor? Sería algo tipo esto: ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');